# How to scroll down in a modal using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, dialog, modal-dialog

[image]

I don't know how to scroll down the modal window.
I tried the method below, but the scroll of the entire outer window goes down, not the modal window.

```java
WebElement element = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/*[last()]"));
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", element);
```

I will attach [the site](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/354986514_Autoantibodies_neutralizing_type_I_IFNs_are_present_in_4_of_uninfected_individuals_over_70_years_old_and_account_for_20_of_COVID-19_deaths), but you have to try to log in to check the list of authors in the modal window

Comment: Why python and Java both are tagged?

Comment: sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

If modal is in Iframe than, Switch to iFrame and then try to scroll down

or use the below

**Method 1**

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver)
act.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).build().perform()
```

**Method 2**

```
EventFiringWebDriver eventfiringWebDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);

        eventfiringWebDriver.executeScript("document.querySelector('.scroll-wrapper').scrollTop=5000")
```

Comment: How do you "switch to iFrame"?

Comment: Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73457426/11863448 its a good way to switch to frame, but its in python. You can switch to Frame in java like `driver.switchTo.frame("Frame_ID");` and to switch to the default again `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`