# Python Selenium Unable to locate element after switching iframe

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

I am unable to locate the "btn" element inside an `iframe` even after switching `iframes`. The code works when I run it through the debugging function, but it does not work when I run it normally. I have also tried `time.sleep`, `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`, explicit waits. I hope that someone will be able to help me out with this issue.

Here is part of the code:

```
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH ,"/html/body/app-root/app-main-layout/mat-drawer-container/mat-drawer-content/app-tools-layout/app-base-sidebar-layout/mat-drawer-container/mat-drawer-content/app-iframe/iframe")

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

time.sleep(30)

print("switch done")

ddate = datetime(2022, 6, 1)

ddate = ddate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

print(ddate)

btn=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='dateFrom']/span/button")

btn.click()
```

Comment: can you share what error you are getting while executing above code.

Comment: checkout this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/73457426/11863448] the best way to switch to frame and switch back from frame

Answer (score 0):

Also I have some error , but I'm getting that element is HtmlObject and selenium can't locate this,
try to print your driver.page_source after and try to find without xpath, find with css selectore or with something else...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33003774)