# Python Selenium - loop over iframes

Tags: python, selenium

I've seen a couple of examples to loop over iframes, but I didn't manage to adapt for myself.

I have list of Webelements which are text input contained inside iframes, i.e: one iframe = one text input.

I've tried this:

```
text_input = self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="Text_input_container__aReGv"]')
iframe_text_input = self.driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "iframe")
for input in text_input:
   self.driver.switch_to.frame(iframe_text_input)
   input_frame = input.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="TextTemplate_editor__1Rkkj"]')
   for text in input_frame:
       text.click()
       text.send_keys(my_text)
```

But this code Selenium throw the error `Element is not attached to the page document`

Thanks for help guys.

Comment: The best way to switch to frame you can check on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73457426/11863448 , this will also resolve the issue you are facing

Comment: Are there multiple iframes on that page, so that each text input is inside another iframe or there is a single iframe and all the text inputs are inside it? Can you share a link to that page?

Comment: Yes there is multiple iframes on that page and each iframes contains a single text input web element for each iframes. Since the page is password protected I can't share a link sorry...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try switching the frame directly by name or by ID:

```
  driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”);
```

or

```
driver.switchTo().frame(“frameId”);
```

If this does not work, try to using XPATH as the selector  instead the CSS_SELECTOR in the loop:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/your/xpath"))
```

I hope it helps.