# How to click on a button that is inside an iframe

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am attempting to find a robust XPath to click a button in the screenshot below

I want to click on the "Inquiry" button
[I want to click on the button "Inquiry"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oql8M.png)

The HTML of the element is made up on the following
[This is the HTML code for the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF9lt.png)

I have tried this code:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/li").click
```

and I am getting this error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find element with xpath == /html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/li
```

Comment: You have to `switch` to the `frame` first you can checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73457426/11863448

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch to the frame before accessing the element.You can use below code to switch to the frame:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
frame = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "frame[name='IDXHeader']")))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

Change locator strategy according based on the attribute available for frame element i.e; By.NAME  or By.XPATH or By.ID.

Since you have ID available for the element. you can directly use ID instead of XPATH. Try below code which will locate Inquiry using ID and clicks on it:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
inquiry = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "mn1sub1")))
inquiry.click()
```

Once you're done accessing element inside frame, switch back to default content using below code:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Entire code should be as below:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
frame = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "frame[name='IDXHeader']")))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
inquiry = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "mn1sub1")))
inquiry.click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: I used your code and it executed properly but it is not clicking on the button and this message is showing: File "c:\Users\dkhare\Desktop\Python_project\envision_bot\envision_login.py", line 28, in <module>
    frame = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "frame_id")))
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dkhare\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: You need to change the locator strategy to locate frame element. I have given sample "frame_id" as you have not provided html for frame . Could you please share html for frame element?

Comment: this is the htlm: 
<frameset border="0" rows="82,*" frameborder="no" framespacing="0">
  <frame marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" border="1" name="IDXHeader" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no" src="MenuBar.action">
  
  <frame marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="IDXWeb" noresize="noresize" scrolling="auto" src="../static/blank.htm" allowtransparency="true" class="main_frame">
  
 </frameset>

Comment: I have edited the answer, assuming your element is inside the frame with name. "IDXHeader". Please try now.

Comment: used the updated code and got this error message: 
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Command not found: POST /session/0732bf74-1af4-4806-86c7-f7c665017105/execute/sync

Comment: Can you try with the updated answer?

Comment: I tried this code: 
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
frame = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "frame[name='IDXHeader']")))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
inquiry = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "mn1sub1")))
inquiry.click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
and I am getting the error message:
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Command not found: POST /session/c41b5184-2fc0-4670-987e-e2e7a871dccd/execute/sync

Comment: Can you try only these three lines of code ```wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)   inquiry = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "mn1sub1")))
inquiry.click()```

Comment: I tried with the 3 line of code as you said and the code executed but it still did not click on the button and this was the message:
File "c:\Users\dkhare\Desktop\Python_project\envision_bot\envision_login.py", line 28, in <module>
    inquiry = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "mn1sub1")))
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\dkhare\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Can you try locating using ```driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//li[@id="mn1sub1"][text()="Inquiry"]').click()``` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[text()='Inquiry']"))).click()
```

In case there is an `iframe`, switch to the desired `iframe` first, after that perform`click()` on <kbd>Inquiry</kbd>.

Example code to switch to `iframe` below:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='iframe']")))
```